# NSPredicate in ObjectiveC is crashing in iOS 11 and working fine in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, ios11

I am using the following code

```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
```

It's crashing if I run the app in iOS 11 but it works fine in iOS 10 devices. Has anybody encountered this? I am really worried this will cause a lot of crash once my current app users get iOS 11 update. If anybody has work around please help[image: Crash logs[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrjDS.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code as text.

Comment: Also include the regex and whatever self is that is causing it to crash

Comment: Including the full trace from the crash log may be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm Having this Issue Too